# TypeError: object() takes no parameters in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my media class

```
class Media:
    _id = None
    _taken_time = None

    def __init__(self, id=None, taken_time=None):
        self._id = id
        self._taken_time = taken_time

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    @yguid.setter
    def id(self, value):
        self._id = value

    @property
    def taken_time(self):
        return self._taken_time

    @taken_time.setter
    def taken_time(self, value):
        self._taken_time = value

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self._id,
            "taken_time": self._taken_time
        }
```

I create a media resource, here

```
class Media(Resource):

    def get(self):
        m = Media('id', 'taken_time')
        return jsonify(m)
        #return jsonify({'id': 'something', 'takenTime': 'something else'})

media_api = Blueprint('resources.media', __name__)
api = Api(media_api)
api.add_resource(
    Media,
    '/medias',
    endpoint='medias'
)
```

When I call this URL this is the error that I get,

```
m = Media('id', 'taken_time')
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I do have a constructor defined that takes two parameters, then why do I still get this error. Any help appreciated.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, as you show two entirely different definitions of class ``Media``.  If the second one is the one that's valid, it has no constructor, so the two parameters are being passed on to its base class ``Resource``, which apparently isn't expecting them.

Comment: @jasonharper yup the naming was actually what led to the error. Thanks fixed it.